# Difference between "Do it yourself" and "Do it by yourself"

Tags: expressions, differences

What is the difference between "Do it yourself" and "Do it **by** yourself"? How and when should I use each of them?

Answer (score 27):

There can be a difference between *yourself* as opposed to *by yourself* in describing an action. To do something *yourself* is to take personal responsibility as opposed to leaving it with a third party. To do something *by yourself* is to do it alone, without the input or assistance of any companions. Sometimes they are interchangeable, but sometimes they are distinct.

*Do it yourself* is closely associated with making repairs and improvements to houses and automobiles without the aid of professionals, to the extent that *do-it-yourself* has entered the dictionary as an adjective (e.g. *do-it-yourself* project or *do-it-yourself* manual) and *DIY* is the name of a television network with shows about people who do their own construction and landscaping.

Consider the following exchanges:

> Neighbor 1: Will you have the contractors paint the garage door?
>
> Neighbor 2: No, I'll do it myself.

The above simply means that Neighbor 2 will not hire contractors to paint the garage door, and will endeavor to do it himself. On the other hand,

> Neighbor 1: Will you have the contractors paint the garage door?
>
> Neighbor 2: No, I'll do it by myself.

In this case, Neighbor 2 not only is not going to hire contractors, but intends to do the painting exclusively himself, without the aid of others, which is likely to suit Neighbor 2's spouse and children just fine.

Comment: I second this ans. +1

Comment: +1. Only great people can understand simple questions are not always as simple as they sound! :)

Comment: _Do it by myself_ implies, to me, that no one else is even at the venue; Neighbor2 even has to get his or her own beer.

Answer (score -1):

*Do it yourself* means just do it without the help of experts and also without the help of any guide, but you might take the help of a friend or anyone who is not professional.
*Do it by yourself* means do it without the help of anyone, whether expert or not.

Answer (score -3):

Do it yourself from a different location from other people pov not as in the same household as you would make you FOLO when you showing other people your work ethic getting up

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).